# How to push multiple key values in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays

By a request I'm having as result some objects like this

```
{
  'pico:record': {
    '$': {
      'xmlns:pico': 'http://purl.org/pico/1.0/',
      'xmlns:dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/',
      'xmlns:dcterms': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/',
      'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
      'xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://purl.org/pico/1.0/    http://purl.org/pico/1.0/pico.xsd'
    },
    'dc:description': [
      'name=Classificazione secondo la graduatoria Guida Rossa TCI; value=*',
      [Object]
    ],
    'dc:identifier': '52800',
    'dc:subject': {
      _: 'http://culturaitalia.it/pico/thesaurus/4.0#mura_fortificazioni',
      '$': [Object]
    },
    'dc:title': { _: 'Mura medievali, Rieti', '$': [Object] },
    'dc:type': { _: 'PhysicalObject', '$': [Object] },
    'dcterms:isReferencedBy': {
      _: 'http://www.touringclub.com/piazza/lazio/rieti/mura-medievali_2.aspx',
      '$': [Object]
    },
    'dcterms:spatial': {
      _: 'PlaceName=viale Morroni ; city=Rieti ; province=RI',
      '$': [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to push to a new array only the "dc:description" and "dc:identifier"

Here the snap of the code

```js
addedData.push(Object.assign({}, item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"], results));
```

Pushing just the "dc:description" works correctly. For example:

```
[
  {
    "addedData": [
      {
        "_": "Lungo le mura, al posto del baluardo nord-est, la cosiddetta Fortezza medicea è un degradato complesso di corpi di fabbrica eretti nella 2ª metà del '500 attorno al trecentesco cassero senese.",
        "$": {
          "xml:lang": "it"
        },
        "result": "Good"
      }
]
```

Adding the "dc:identifier" like this

```js
addedData.push(Object.assign({}, item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"],["dc:identifier"], results));
```

I'm having a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "addedData": [
      {
        "0": "dc:identifier",
        "_": "Lungo le mura, al posto del baluardo nord-est, la cosiddetta Fortezza medicea è un degradato complesso di corpi di fabbrica eretti nella 2ª metà del '500 attorno al trecentesco cassero senese.",
        "$": {
          "xml:lang": "it"
        },
        "result": "Good"
      }
]
```

Without the relative ID number for the "dc:description"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: very confusing actions, 'dc:description' as i see is an array, then why you add it through Object.assign? The same about ["dc:identifier"], which is number, what do you expect when you add it through Object.assign...And what is results in your expression? It is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because :

```
addedData.push(Object.assign({}, item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"],["dc:identifier"], results));
```

Should be :

```
addedData.push(Object.assign({}, item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"], item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:identifier"], results));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy just two fields you can do like this

```
function copyTwoProps(obj, prop1, prop2) {
  return {
    [prop1]: obj[prop1],
    [prop2]: obj[prop2]
  }
}

const newObj = copyTwoProps(
  item.metadata["pico:record"], 
  'dc:description', 
  'dc:identifier'
)
```